# How Can I Remove Oil Stains From Carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet, stain

Today, a bottle of oil slipped from my hand and fell onto the carpet. I tried removing the oil from the carpet by rubbing it with detergent, but it is not coming out.  Can anyone tell me a better way to remove the oil from the carpet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do your best at everybody else's tips here but if it still doesn't come out I would call a Chem-Dry carpet cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have 3 items to clean up your carpet
1. Denatured alcohol
2. Any water based cleaning detergent
3. A piece of towel
**Method.**
Pour some denatured alcohol on to the piece of towel and gently blot the stain spot and do this for some time and then pour some cleaning detergent onto the piece of towel and do the same blotting and you will notice the stain is removing within some time.
**Remember** you need not to rub the towel against carpet as it will generate heat which will take the twist and lay out of your carpet yearns.

Answer (score 0):

Car oil is only difficult to clean because the right chemicals to remove it aren't present in regular household cleaners. In particular, you'll need Polyether Amine (PEA) to counter the carbon in car oil. You can use any product with PEA as an active ingredient - especially injector cleaners.

I've had this problem before as well, but on cement. I diluted some car injection cleaner and scrubbed at the cement. Then, I put vinegar and lemon to make it smell better. Worked pretty well.

Comment: Harold, thanks for the useful answer! Since your links went to a specific site, and that's not what this community is about, they've been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Auto mechanic hand cleaner, a white solid that looks like mayonnaise , Go-Jo is one brand. Not irritating to skin . Rub it in and let it sit , it will loosen or dissolve most stuff such as pine sap, and ,of course auto grease and oil. Wipe it up with paper or cloth towels. It is water soluble ,so follow up with water rinse and soak out any remainder.